# tablesaw - jQuery plugin for responsive design HTML table does not work in the case of ajax call

Tags: responsive-design, html-table

I am using [tablesaw](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/tablesaw.html) to build an HTML table with responsive design. It works pretty well when I just use the code directly in my php (i.e. Codeigniter ) webpage . But it does not work if on clicking  a button ( i.e. form submit) an ajax call is made and the full HTML for the responsive table is fetched from this call and then displayed in the page. It just becomes a non-resposive  HTML table.

The ajax call i.e. the form submission is done with [jQuery Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

HTML :

```
<div class="result"></div>

    <form class="form_action" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form_action" 
method="post" action="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>index/show_order_details_now">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn_submit" name="submit_evoucher" />

    </form>
```

JS:

```
 $(form).ajaxSubmit({
      target: '.result', 
      success: function(response) {
       $(".result").html(response);

      }
    });
```

the function being called is :

```
function show_order_details_now(){

    ?>


    <?php

$orders_paid='  <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.JSPATH.'tablesaw-master/dist/tablesaw.css"/>

        <table   class="tablesaw purchase_details_tbl_1"  data-tablesaw-mode="columntoggle" ><thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="1">Invoice No</th>



                    <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-sortable-default-col data-tablesaw-priority="3">Product Code</th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="persist">Product Name</th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="2">Specification</th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="1">Quantity</th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="2">Rate</th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">Sub Total(Tk)</th>
                </tr>
            </thead><tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
            </tr>';




            //echo '<br/><b> order iddd = '.$order_id.'</b>';







        $orders_paid.='</tbody></table>';





        echo $orders_paid;



}// end of function show_order_details_now
```

So how to make the table responsive in this case as `tablesaw` is supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
jQuery(document).trigger('enhance.tablesaw');
```

Once you've inserted your table into the DOM.